# Updating VPC-CNI add-on on EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to update VPC CNI on a EKS cluster and getting this error `Updating VPC-CNI can only go up or down 1 minor version at a time`, after I tried to update only one minor version I got `Addon version specified is not supported` error so how should I do the update.

The cluster version is 1.27 my current VPC CNI version is 1.10.1 and I want to update it with terraform.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 2):

I deleted it in the UI and reinstalled it. Please note, I did this on an eks cluster with no pods running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the update path for vpc-cni addon with supported versions (as per UI or documentation) ensuring 1 minor version update at a time
[image: Update Versions available for vpc-cni addon for EKS Master 1.27]

```
   Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["vpc-cni"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_eks_addon" "this" {
      ~ addon_version        = "v1.13.4-eksbuild.1" -> "v1.14.1-eksbuild.1"
        id                   = "tajawal-dev:vpc-cni"
        tags                 = {}
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```